# Why would I use Reflection in a business app?

Tags: .net, reflection

I know what Reflection is but why would I need to use it in a typical line-of-business Winforms app?

Comment: All valid points and I can see the use if, for example, I'm writing a unit testing framework or something but in terms of LOB apps in a corporate environment?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, my question is quite specific and I'm not looking for a general primer.

Comment: I agree, voted for reopening.

Comment: Uh... What's so special about line-of-business apps? Why would they *not* need something as useful as reflection?

Answer (score 11):

One common scenario is to reflect through assemblies to find, load and use plugins for your application.

We also use reflection extensively in the Factory Pattern. Object creation methods can be marked with attributes with are found with reflection and then created by our factory.

In fact, any use of attributes uses reflection. If you create your own attributes, you will use reflection to find them on your code.

We also use reflection to generate code. We have a client/server application that uses .NET remoting. We mark the calls into our server with our own attributes and then use reflection to find them and generate all of our communications code, an assembly for the server and one for the client. It saves all of the rote work of manually adding in the same logging, timing and remoting code everywhere.

Comment: i have yet to see a "typical line-of-business WinForms app" that used or needed plug-ins ;-)

Comment: I think that depends on how you define a line-of-business app ;-) If it is an app developed internally, then probably not, but if it is an externally developed app for business customers, then it is highly likely. Our Enterprise app has plugins to interface with other Enterprise apps.

Comment: Due to a drawn out deployment process for applications, we used generic code built on reflection and externally configured forms, built at runtime, to speed up deployment. This was an internal only application for 500 users.

Answer (score 4):

Reflection can help you write more maintanable code and reduce the amount of code for some specific task.

I.e. you could write a simple shell either by using a lot of **if** statements to match a command, or use reflection to generate a dictionary containing delegates to methods marked with a specific custom attribute to expose it to the user. With the reflection approach, such method only has to be added in a single place and reflection takes care of the rest.

Answer (score 2):

That's kind of loaded question, but some reasons come to mind:

- Testing private methods in unit tests.
- Using it to sort dynamically with linq when having only a property name available.
- Fill an object's property on the fly.  Possibly because you are matching the property to a datarow column name or maybe and xml element. (Might be an outdated use)
- Creating a class on the fly.

Answer (score 2):

Another common use for reflection is serialization.  .Net uses reflection to find type information when serializing objects.  A line of business app might want to provide a custom data import/export feature, and serialization via reflection is one way to accomplish that.

Answer (score 2):

I've defined an a DisplayName attribute for my Enum's so you end with:

enum
{
 [DisplayName("Opened")
 open,
 [DisplayName("Request for Quote")
 RFQ

}

Now I can using reflection to pull out the right label. This is handy for data driven applications. You can also put a resource key in there so you can localize it.

I'll use reflection if I want to process somethign based on it's type. So if Im passed Type A go left otherwise go right.

Answer (score 1):

You can build user interfaces dynamically based on your DTO's if you happen to use them.

Answer (score 1):

It makes the Factory pattern real easy to expand because you can put information in a config file or a database (and the Factory itself becomes code you never have to touch).

Answer (score 1):

assuming by "line of business app" you mean "a simple CRUD app", then you've defined the scope narrowly enough that you probably do not need reflection to make it work - or even to make it better

reflection makes the language "closed" in the sense that operators in the language can be used to investigate operators in the language; contrast this with the C language, which has no reflection. Want to call a function by name in C? Can't do it, no reflection.

Does the typical C application need to do this? No, or rarely.

Similarly per your question "Why would I use Reflection in a business app?" the answer is that *you* probably wouldn't, while others *may* have clever uses for it, but in fact for basic CRUD applications it is not "necessary".

that doesn't mean that you shouldn't understand it; knowing what it is and what it can do can mean the difference between writing a ton of brittle code or a little elegant reflective code, in the event that you ever encounter something more difficult or complex than a 'line of business app' ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here are just some of the many samples:

- **Auto-discover and load components and services** within the .NET Inversion of Control Container that we use with *.NET reflection*
- **Enforce design constraints over the code** (i.e. "All classes in the Model namespace must be immutable and serilizable") with Cecil-based reflection ([sample](http://rabdullin.com/journal/2008/10/14/writing-net-code-analysis-rules-as-unit-tests.html))
- **Add sanity and validation checks** to the code to make it more stable with helpers implemented with the IL-based reflection ([sample](http://rabdullin.com/journal/2008/12/19/how-to-get-parameter-name-and-argument-value-from-c-lambda-v.html#comment2686418)).
- **Bind UI controls and error providers to the business objects and business rules** with the .NET reflection based on Linq expressions ([sample](http://rabdullin.com/journal/2008/12/18/development-compromises-around-lambda-expressions.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Likely uses:

- [creating LINQ expressions](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2008/10/express-yourself.html) by hand
- serialization, either inbuilt or [bespoke](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/)
- data-binding
- data import/export, for example via [`HyperDescriptor`](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/HyperPropertyDescriptor.aspx)
- dynamic code generation (`Reflection.Emit`)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement the Factory pattern and avoid having to recompile a code everytime you add a new component in the factory, Reflection may be the only option.

Answer (score 0):

We use reflection in many places, including:

- to implement dependency injection and factory pattern
- serialization
- controlling behavior via class attributes

Answer (score 0):

We use reflection to be able to map the controls from the UI layer directly to the properties of the business object in the datalayer.  This lets you have a 'generic' function on a baseForm someplace that 'auto populates' the BO with the UI data and vice-versa, without having to write code for each and every control and property on the form and object.